# Customizing ember.js hasMany records' key on serialization

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to customize a hasMany relationship's key when serializing and posting the data to the server. Something like:

```js
const thread = DS.Model.extend({
  emails: hasMany('email')
})

const email = DS.Model.extend({
  thread: belongsTo('thread')
})
```

When a thread is saved, I'm serializing the related `emails` records using the EmbededdedRecordsMixin. I want to change the key (which, by default, is `emails`) to `emails_attributes` *only* when the thread is serialized.

I've done that by customizing the serialize function on the `ThreadSerializer`:

```js
serialize () {
  const thread = this._super(...arguments)
  thread.emails_attributes = thread.emails
  delete thread.emails
  return thread
}
```

That also works. However, I'm not sure that's the correct way to approach this. I've looked at the docs, but I'm unable to find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the `RESTSerializer`?

Comment: I'm using the ActiveModelSerializer.